# Why does mousedown event listener run through function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, click, addeventlistener

I drew a canvas, and then with the code

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", clicked(event), false);
```

I added an event listener to run clicked whenever I click the mouse.
But when I went through the code line by line on chrome, the moment it adds the event listener it automatically runs the function clicked anyway, but I only want it to run the function when I click.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try `clicked` without `(event)`

Comment: @basilikum is right. You're invoking the function. Just pass it as `clicked`.

Comment: OMG WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOW would you believe I spent like an hour on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just pass the function reference and not actually call it like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", clicked, false);
```

Then, the function should be defined like this:

```
function clicked(event) {
    // code here
}
```

When you include parens after the function name, it is immediately executed and it's return value is what is passed to `addEventListener()` which is probably not what you wanted at all.  Leave off the parens to just pass a function reference.

Answer (score 0):

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", clicked,false);